# Salesforce: Can I associate a completion of a task with a field update?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to see if it's possible for a field in Opportunity to be updated (a checkbox to be checked true) when someone completes a related task. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Great question and although it looks like you have an answer, I'd recommend using #askforce for twitter questions or go to http://success.salesforce.com/answers and leverage our community for answers as well. Hope that helps! Nathan

Comment: @salesforce.com Coming to [so] to actively solicit users to your site and away from ours is perhaps not the wisest thing to do. However, we'd be glad if you could join us and answer questions on salesforce here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with cross-object workflow, since the `WhatId` field of a `Task` is a "polymorphic key". If I'm right, you'll have to use a Trigger on `Task`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing triggers for it but it looks like it may be the only solution. Thanks

Comment: Cross-object workflow? How is that possible? http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrrsAAC

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy said you'll need a trigger, code will look something like (I've not checked field names etc. so treat this as almost-real pseudo code)!

```
trigger TaskAfterInsertUpdate on Task (after update, after insert)
{
    list<opportunity> liOpportunities = new list<opportunity>();
    list<id> liIDs = new list<id>();

    for(Task sTask : trigger.new)
    {
        if(sTask.Status == 'Complete' && ('' + sTask.WhatId).startsWith('006'))
        {
            liIDs.add(sTask.WhatId);
        }
    }

    for(Opportunity sOppty : [select Id, CheckBoxField__c from Opportunity where Id in : liIDS])
    {
        sOppty.CheckBoxField__c = true;
        liOpportunities.add(sOppty);
    }

    update liOpportunities;
}
```

Hope this is of some help!